How to specify the entered coordinates as the right centre of the text in Matplotlib?
When generating text in Matplotlib, how to make the entered coordinates the right centre of the text?
Example code:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])

Plot line with text:
s.plot()
plt.text(1, 2, 'Apple')


Desired output:


plt.text(1, 2, 'Apple', ha='right', va='center')  Found it, thank you all!
